# Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in my-path-to-root/my-site/includes/entity.inc on line 320

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am moving a site over to a different server to test.

getting this error

> Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in my-path-to-root/my-site/includes/entity.inc on line 320

strange... if i try accessing a subdirectry http://www.mysite/randomstuff
i get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in /home/borsodas3/digipowers.devserver2012.com/modules/overlay/overlay.module on line 130
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_access_needs_rebuild() in /home/borsodas3/digipowers.devserver2012.com/sites/all/modules/taxonomy_access/taxonomy>_access.module on line 598

here are the two php.info files

- going to this server [http://www.freeenergymedia.com/phpinfo-to.htm][1]
- from this one [http://www.freeenergymedia.com/phpinfo-from.htm][2]

the drupal status report from the site I am migrating FROM looks like this...

```
Info
Drupal  7.8
OK
Access to update.php    Protected
Error
CTools CSS Cache    Unable to create
The CTools CSS cache directory, ctools/css could not be created due to a misconfigured files directory. Please ensure that the files directory is correctly configured and that the webserver has permission to create directories.
OK
Configuration file  Protected
OK
Credit card encryption  Credit card data is encrypted during checkout for maximum security.
OK
Cron maintenance tasks  Last run 26 min ago
You can run cron manually.
To run cron from outside the site, go to mysite.com
OK
Database system MySQL, MariaDB, or equivalent
OK
Database system version 5.1.57-log
OK
Database updates    Up to date
OK
Date API    System date settings
The timezone has been set to America/New_York. The first day of the week has been set to Monday. The medium date format has been set to to F j, Y - g:ia.
Error
Drupal core update status   Not secure! (version 7.12 available)
There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
OK
File system Writable (public download method)
OK
Fitvids library Installed
Fitvids Javascript Library. Download it from here, copy it to the module directory, and rename it to jquery.fitvids.js.
OK
GD library PNG support  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
OK
GD library rotate and desaturate effects    bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
OK
Images  Product image support has been automatically configured by Ubercart.
Error
Module and theme update status  Not secure!
There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
OK
Node Access Permissions 1832 permissions in use
If the site is experiencing problems with permissions to content, you may have to rebuild the permissions cache. Rebuilding will remove all privileges to content and replace them with permissions based on the current modules and settings. Rebuilding may take some time if there is a lot of content or complex permission settings. After rebuilding has completed, content will automatically use the new permissions. Rebuild permissions
OK
PHP 5.3.2 (more information)
OK
PHP extensions  Enabled
OK
PHP memory limit    300M
OK
PHP register globals    Disabled
Warning
Unicode library Standard PHP
Operations on Unicode strings are emulated on a best-effort basis. Install the PHP mbstring extension for improved Unicode support.
OK
Update notifications    Enabled
Info
Upload progress Not enabled
Your server is capable of displaying file upload progress through APC, but it is not enabled. Add apc.rfc1867 = 1 to your php.ini configuration. Alternatively, it is recommended to use PECL uploadprogress, which supports more than one simultaneous upload.
OK
Web server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
OK
cURL    Enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is update to the latest version of Drupal Core. The error message you are seeing is coming from core, but could be from a contrib module. Update all your modules if any are as outdated as your Drupal core is. There are security issues in Drupal 7.8 and other issues which might affect your situation could well have been resolved. The current version of Drupal is 7.12 and a lot has been fixed since Drupal 7.8, which was released about 6 months ago, so you definitely want to upgrade core. Is it also possible that you are running different versions of core on the different machines? If so, the database might not be compatible, especially if you are taking a newer database (more recent modules and core) and loading it into a system with older modules/core.

After also updating other contrib modules and running update.php at appropriate times, if your problem still persists, you might want to use the "divide and conquer" method to identify which module is actually responsible. Remove groups of contrib modules and see where the problem disappears, then narrow it down to which one is causing the problem. It could also be a compatibility issue or configuration problem. Or you might have modules where the code has been updated, but update.php hasn't been run so the database isn't what it should be. You can also use tools such as the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module to try to track down issues, but it depends on how "broken" your site is. If you are getting "fatal errors", then you might first want to see what you can do to get past that.

I also notice you need to properly set the permissions/ownership of your files directory so that CSS caching can take place (among other tasks the webserver may be trying to do and which could also be involved in errors you are experiencing), even if not at the root of the "fatal errors".

Hope that helps some… troubleshooting can be a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed for the  first  time,  I  hadn`t checked "Create new  database" and  had the same  bag but  in line  321.[image]